# Cloudfront generating 302 redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to figure out why my CldouFront distribution, which points to my own domain, is resulting in http/2 302 results, rather than 200's.

My actual file is here:

```
~ curl -I https://svelte.mylibrary.io/assets/Home.e42d622a.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=432000
Last-Modified: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:03:12 GMT
Etag: W/"15bd5-17e88522580"
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 89045
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:08:04 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

This is what I'm seeing when I request it via my CloudFront distribution

```
~ curl -I https://d3u39p1wo246y.cloudfront.net/assets/Home.e42d622a.js
HTTP/2 302
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
content-length: 73
location: https://svelte.mylibrary.io/assets/Home.e42d622a.js
server: Cowboy
x-powered-by: Express
date: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:08:14 GMT
via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 e1cb26f55af020d51729c02b0fb5db98.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
vary: Origin
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-amz-cf-pop: DFW50-C1
x-amz-cf-id: 33uqK_-E-U-Sfxm4Zava7VATMWQrZ-vBxeM49wR12LB2RRGocEuP7Q==
```

There's nothing too crazy about my CloudFront distribution. I've set my domain to `svelte.mylibrary.io`, and I've enabled CORS with preflight.

Is there something in the response headers of my own file that CloudFront is not liking, such that it refuses to send the 200 onward?

The domain is hosted on Heroku, and served up by Express's static middleware.

Some info on the CloudFront setup

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT

I have another CF distribution for my top-level mylibrary.io domain, and it successfully forwards the 200 result

```
~ curl -I https://mylibrary.io/assets/FlexRow.60393e4b.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=432000
Last-Modified: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:02:40 GMT
Etag: W/"137-17e8851a880"
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 311
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:31:55 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

```
~ curl -I https://d2esd5amemogpi.cloudfront.net/assets/FlexRow.60393e4b.js
HTTP/2 200
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 311
server: Cowboy
x-powered-by: Express
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: public, max-age=432000
last-modified: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:02:40 GMT
etag: W/"137-17e8851a880"
date: Sun, 23 Jan 2022 19:23:55 GMT
via: 1.1 vegur, 1.1 6c6707b9b2a2151353d87b53eeed3030.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Origin
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
x-amz-cf-pop: DFW53-C1
x-amz-cf-id: hnosyh2UKCfU8hfCnISVmrHPeF7OBT5p7V4Gdh2wAqCrA2GA94fHSw==
```

Comment: It looks like it is simply redirecting the CloudFront domain "d3u39p1wo246y.cloudfront.net" to your custom domain "svelte.mylibrary.io". Do you not want it to do that?

Comment: I was expecting that hitting the CloudFront endpoint would return a 200 result, like I'm seeing my distribution on my top-level mylibrary.io domain do.

Comment: You realize 302 isn't an error message, right? You shouldn't be giving anyone the `d2esd5amemogpi.cloudfront.net` domain name. All requests should be going to your custom domain. All CloudFront is doing is taking any requests that aren't to that custom domain, and redirecting them to the custom domain.

Comment: @MarkB why doesn't it do that for the file on mylibrary.io then, which I added to the question? I thought the whole point of CF is that I request these resources from the CF CDN, to leverage their caching and such.

Comment: @AdamRackis, did you find the solution, as I am facing the same issue? CloudFront is sending a redirect 302

Comment: Is the configuration exactly the same for the top-level domain, as it is for the sub-domain? Perhaps there's something there in the Behaviours specific to one of them.